# Не работает загрузчик и ядро в qemu

Tags: ассемблер, fasm, qemu

Написал загрузчик и транслирую его с помощью fasm для загрузки написанного ядра. Запускаю все это через  qemu при помощи команды "qemu -fda bootsect.bin -fdb kernel.bin".При этом в окне qemu пишет что "Booting from Floppy....  Boot failed: not a bootable disk". В чем причина?

Код bootsect.asm

```
use16

start:
cli
mov ax, cs                 ; Сохранение адреса сегмента кода в ax
mov ds, ax                 ; Сохранение этого адреса как начало сегмента данных
mov ss, ax                 ; И сегмента стека
mov sp, start              ; Сохранение адреса стека как адрес первой инструкции этого кода. Стек будет расти вверх и не перекроет код.
sti

load_drive:
    mov ax, 0x1000
    mov es, ax
    mov ax, 0x0
    mov al, 0x18           ; sum of sectors to read
    mov dl, 0x01           ; number of drive
    mov dh, 0x00           ; number of head
    mov ch, 0x00           ; number of track(cylinder)
    mov cl, 0x01           ; number of sector
    mov ah, 0x02           ; function for int 0x13
    int 0x13               ; read data from 0x1000

enable_protected_mode:
    cli                    ; off interrupts
    lgdt [gdt_info]          ; Загрузка размера и адреса таблицы дескрипторов
    in al, 0x92            ; Включение адресной линии А20
    or al, 0x02 
    out 0x92, al
    mov eax, cr0           ; Установка бита PE регистра CR0 - процессор перейдет в защищенный режим
    or al, 0x01
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp 0x8:protected_mode ; "Дальний" переход для загрузки корректной информации в cs


use32
protected_mode:
    mov ax, 0x10          ; Загрузим регистры DS и SS селектором сегмента данных
    mov es, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    call 0x10000
gdt:
db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
db 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x9A, 0xCF, 0x00
db 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x92, 0xCF, 0x00
gdt_info:
dw gdt_info - gdt
dw gdt, 0
    times (512 - ($ - start) - 2)
    db 0x55, 0xAA
```

Код kernel.asm

```
use32 ; 32-битный код
org 0x10000 ; Адрес, по которому будет загружен этот код загрузчиком ядра
mov edi, 0xb8000
mov esi, str_hello
call video_puts
; В регистр edi помещается адрес начала буфера
; В регистр esi помещается адрес начала строки
; Вызывается функция для видеовывода в буфер
infinite_loop:
; Перевод процессора в бесконечный цикл
hlt
jmp infinite_loop
video_puts:
; Функция выводит в буфер видеопамяти (передается в edi) строку,
; После завершения edi содержит адрес по которому можно продолжать
mov al, [esi]
test al, al
jz video_puts_end
mov ah, 0x07 ; Цвет символа и фона. Возможные варианты: 0x00 is
;black-on-black, 0x07 is lightgrey-on-black, 0x1F is white-on-blue
mov [edi], al
mov [edi+1], ah
add edi, 2
add esi, 1
jmp video_puts
video_puts_end:
ret
str_hello:
db "Welcome to HelloWorldOS (asm edition)!", 0
```

Comment: не знаю как qemu на это реагирует, но у вас DL в int 13 соответствует диску B:

Comment: К сожалению,это никак не помогло